# C# Web api check that JWT token sender is equal to parameter of endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Web API project. I'm using JWT Token and I have a RolePermissionFilter class. I'm controlling user's permission but I noticed something, If someone have token after login can send request for other user.

```
[HttpPut]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(VM_Update_User model)
    {
        return Ok(await _userWrite.updateUser( _mapper.Map<DTO_Update_User>(model) ));
    }
```

How can I check that JWT token sender is equal to parameter of endpoint and What else should I do to secury my api.